# fullCalendar: how to customize header

Tags: fullcalendar

I have 5 calendars on same page, every one of them related to a different agenda. Only the day view is available.
I need to put an identifying header for each agenda, not just showing the day of week.
I don't know how to do this, any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the columnFormat option to control what's in the header for a particular day.

If you want custom text in there (i.e. not just date formatting strings) then you can enclose any text like that within square brackets.

For example

```
columnFormat: '[Hello, World!] dddd',
```

would result in something like "Hello, World! Thursday" (depending on the day of the week, obviously).

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/ for more detail.

Comment: @plectranthus no problem. Don't forget to "accept" the answer as well, if it worked for you - thanks :-)